# Google recently changed my title. How to restore to my original title or prevent google doing so?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, title, seo-audit

I think I have the best title given on one of my webpage and was getting a good CTR. Google recently seems to change titles of some of my important pages. **How to restore to my original title or prevent google doing so?**

I used my brand name ahead of my title, however I have removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your titles. Make sure the titles are in the right length, they don't have any confilct (duplicated titles) and they present the content of the pages well.